# How can I contribute ports?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to port https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c to VxWorks. I have created 2 PRs:

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/pull/2022
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/pull/538

I have signed the CLA but don't know **how to proceed**.

I have referred the contribution guide: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md.
But the section "Contributing Ports" is TBD.

My PRs seem stuck there. All CI checks are pending.

Could you please let me know what I should do next?

Comment: Alex, I have notified to the author for a review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your PR! Getting the VxWorks RTOS ported to work with Azure IoT services seems to be a great idea. The only caveat here is choosing the right SDK to get this done: in your case you used the [C SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c) which can be too big for constrained devices.
The **best** SDK for constrained devices and porting a RTOS would be the [Embedded C SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c/tree/main/sdk/docs/iot) which is smaller, non-allocating, and very flexible as it allows you to use whichever MQTT, TLS and Socket your target platform needs.